# Chrome Extension [DEV] - is LocalStorage for a Extension Per Account or System Wide?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, user-accounts

I'm developing an exentension that uses localStorage, my question is if there are multiple accounts per PC, does the extension use separate storage per user or is it system/extension wide?